# Что за конструкция <?=

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Скинули проект мне тут, запускаю и не работает. Глянул в html-теги. 
Встречаю:         
    <?=$var['name']?>

Что это? = вместо echo?

П.С. Под денвером вроде работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывод. Причем именно в таком виде, оно очень не любит пробелов.

Comment: @knes, пробелов нет. Может конфиг надо подправить? У меня ручная связка. А гугл "съедает" спец символы, поэтому сюда и обратился

Comment: Можете либо заменить на   

  <?php print $var['name'];?>

Либо на  

    <?php echo $var['name'];?>

Если и после этого работать не будет, значит-таки гугл.

Comment: @knes, да будет наверно. Только вот проект большой и искать эти конструкции не очень хочется.

Comment: А все не надо. Достаточно одну заменить и посмотреть.
Какая у вас версия PHP? Просто если меньше 5.4, то там, вроде бы, надо было разрешать 

short_open_tag = enabled;

Comment: @knes, действительно нужно было просто короткие теги разрешить. Спасибо)